# Unable to send APNS message with Distribution Certificate

Tags: c#, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, x509certificate2, sslstream

I have setup and successfully tested APNS messaging with a development certificate and `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`. 
 When I change over to my distribution certificate and `gateway.push.apple.com` the messages aren't getting through and I am getting an exception:

Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

I have followed these tutorials to generate a p12 certificate:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate

The server software I am sending the notifications from is a .NET application using the `SslStream` and `X509Certificate2` classes.

Below is the connection code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Establish connection to Apple's Push Notification System using the variables in the config file.
    /// </summary>
    public void ConnectToAPNS()
    {
        try
        {
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(Config.SSL_PORT ); // 2195
                // pick the target address
            String hostname = Config.SSL_PATH;  // gateway.push.apple.com

            //load certificate
            string certificatePath = Config.CERT_FILE; //.p12 certification file
            string certificatePassword = Config.CERT_PASS;
            byte[] p12Data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath);

            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(p12Data, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificatesCollection.Add(clientCertificate);

            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback remote = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

            client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            sslStream = new SslStream(
                    client.GetStream(),
                    false,
                    remote,
                    null
            );

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, true);

            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                IQLogger.Logger.LogError("Push NotifyMessenger ConnectToAPNS: " + e.Message);
                client.Close();
                sslStream = null;
                client = null;
                return;
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            IQLogger.Logger.LogError("PushNotifyMessenger ConnectToAPNS: " + e.Message);
            sslStream = null;
            client = null;
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call back checks for validation error
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ValidateServerCertificate( object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        try{
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;
        }
        catch 
        {
        }
        IQLogger.Logger.LogError("PushNotifyMessenger ValidateServerCertificate: sslPolicyErrors" + sslPolicyErrors);
        // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers. 
        return false;
    }
```

This is the code to send a message :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// I send a text message to a specified device ID. I provide an example of how to format a message for the APNS system. 
    /// The message must be formatted in Json and be sent as a byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceId"> A string containing 64 characters representing hexidecimal values of a 32 byte device code</param>
    /// <param name="msgPrompt">The text that will popup on the device </param>
    /// <param name="msgData"> XML that will be put in the XML json Section. This data will be invisible to the recipient's user, 
    /// but will be accessible by the recipient program</param>
    public void SendMessage(string deviceId, string msgPrompt, string msgData)
    {
        try{
            if (client == null || sslStream == null)
            {
                ConnectToAPNS();
            }

            // Encode a test message into a byte array.
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
            writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)

            byte[] arDeviceID = ConvertDeviceID(deviceId);//System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(deviceId);
            writer.Write(arDeviceID);

            String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + msgPrompt + "\",\"badge\":1,\"xml\":\"" + msgData + "\"}}";

            writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)
            writer.Write((byte)payload.Length); //payload length (big-endian second byte)

            byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            writer.Write(b1);
            writer.Flush();

            byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            sslStream.Write(array);   // <<<<<<<<<< exception thrown here
            sslStream.Flush();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IQLogger.Logger.LogError("PushNotifyMessenger.SendMessage: " + e.Message);
            return;
        }

    }
```

The exception is thrown on the 2nd or 3rd try to send an APNS message. However none of the messages ever gets through to the device. I can swap back to my development certificate and this code functions just fine (and the APNS messages arrive at the device).

In my search to resolve the problem I have encountered posts stating that the development certificate is somehow interfering with the deployment one however I do not understand how this is happening or what I should do to resolve it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using APNS live server URL *ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195*